# How can I detect the name of my current URL if I include my php script on another page?

Tags: php

This is my `home.php`:

```
require('header.php');
```

This is my `header.php`

```
if (basename(__FILE__) == "home.php"){
        echo "you are on home.php"; 
} else {
        echo "you are not on home.php";
}
```

When I now open the URL `www.mypage.com/home.php` I see the text `you are not on home.php`

Comment: `__FILE__` is a macro which will always return the filename in which it is defined - i.e. in this case, it will always equal `"header.php"`. Answers to this question may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: @TomLord Yes, but this gives me the full URL, this is not what I need. I need only the filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?php
    $explode = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $explode = explode("?", $explode[count($explode)-1]);

    echo $explode[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost working well, the problem is still that I now get the URL `home.php?id=22` as a result. I would only need `home.php`

Comment: `<?php echo "<pre/>";print_r(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));?>` and check what outputs?

Comment: I've updated the code, it should work now as you want it :)

Comment: I tested this: `$test = $explode[count($explode)-1];` and this `echo substr($test, 0, strpos($test, "?"));` It is working

Comment: That's another way of doing it :) Glad i could help you